# Sunburn Soothing and Removing Tips and Tricks?

Tags: personal-care, comfort

Obviously you can't simply remove a sunburn, that'd be nice.  I am just wondering if anyone knows any tips or tricks to soothe it and/or make it go away faster?  Other than obvious things like lotion, sunscreen, and pain medicine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. **Cool Milk**

Soak a wash cloth in cool milk and keep in soaked until the wash cloth gets completely saturated with cold milk. Let the excess milk drain off. Now, drape the wash cloth around the affected part.

2. **Cucumber, Rose Water and Lemon Juice Pack**

The acidic property of lemon acts as a natural bleach in removing tan and fighting pimples.  The cucumber juice and rose water acts as cooling agents for soothing the blemished skin. Take a table spoon each of cucumber juice, lemon juice and rose water and mix in a bowl. Apply with cotton on tanned areas, wait for 10 minutes and wash off with cold water. Apply this pack every day after you get back home from the sun.

3. You can also use **Aloe Vera** gel.

**Caution**: I am not sure how lemon will work if your face skin gets tanned. So don't include lemon if your face skin is tanned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try plain black tea.  You soak a paper towel in the tea and lay it on the affected area.  You may need help depending on where this is.  Leave it on your back until the towel is dry.  Not sure why this works but my mother did it for us when we were younger and it seemed to help. Then there are the more obvious lotions.  Aloe Vera gel works well, but actual Aloe Vera from the plant works better if you have one/can get one.